# Error in starting react project

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

i'm facing problem while start react project.

first i tried yarn start. shows this error
[image]

than i tried npm start. shows this error
[image]

structure
[image]

what is this error??

node -v : v6.11.2

npm --v: 3.10.10

OS: ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1):

okay I got it. all that problem is occurred due to my webpack. i solve it by:

1. `npm run eject`
2. `npm install`
3. `npm --save --dev update`

and i think `npm run eject` is not required at all