# How to solve "npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE" error in Linux?

Tags: reactjs, npm, linux-mint

I am working on a React project. Every day while I try to start the project, I face "npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE". But somehow I solve this problem by getting help from these two links.

[npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308879/npm-err-code-elifecycle)

[Error in starting react project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47467126/error-in-starting-react-project)

How can I solve the issue permanently?

Comment: Please let me know, why am I getting minus score, so that I can understand my mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Linux solution**
start project with this command

```
sudo npm start
```